# Continuation-passing style and the lambda calculus

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, lambda-calculus, monads

I am looking for an example of continuation passing style which does not involve any examples from programming languages; in particular, an example which involves a reduction sequence from the lambda calculus would be very useful.

If I search for "continuation passing style" on the internet, all I can find are examples from programming languages, which make little sense to me. How can the technique be illustrated by something from the lambda calculus?

I am trying to read Phillip Wadler's "Monads and composable continuations", and having at least some preliminary understanding of what continuation passing would be in the lambda calculus would be useful.

Comment: You posted an example from lambda calculus 5 hours ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661660/the-definition-of-the-factorial-using-continuations-in-the-lambda-calculus

Answer (score 3):

If we to add two numbers we could use the expression
$$
\lambda n,m. n+m.
$$
If we switch this to continuation passing style we need add another parameter, the continuation function, $k$. Then we have
$$
\lambda n,m,k. k(n+m)
$$
The only difference is that, instead of returning a value, we pass the return value to the continuation.  It's not any different in $\lambda$ calculus than in any other programming language.

Things are a little more interesting when we have a function defined by recursion; in this case it can easier to change the continuation to an anonymous function that calls the original continuation.  The example at "[The definition of the factorial using continuations in the Lambda calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661660/the-definition-of-the-factorial-using-continuations-in-the-lambda-calculus) " demonstrates how to do this.

In the context of addition, a recursive definition might be
$$
Y \lambda f \lambda n,m.  \text{if } n = 0 \text{ then } m \text{ else } 1 + f(n-1,m).
$$
To switch this to continuation passing style we could use something like this: 
$$
Y \lambda f \lambda n,m\lambda k.  \text{if } n = 0 \text{ then } k(m) \text{ else } f(n-1, m, \lambda v. k(v+1)).
$$
Of course, in the end, the second one still ends up calling $k(n+m)$ once all the intermediate anonymous functions are evaluated.

Comment: Ok, so continuation passing style in terms of reduction sequences of the lambda calculus is form of reduction of lambda terms which are altered so that they express their continuized variants, upon which reduction is then performed?

Comment: I don't see the reduction itself as much different, just the way that the return value of the function is handled.

Comment: But then what precisely is the difference between a continuation and continuation-passing style?

Comment: So continuation passing style is computations in the lambda calculus using continuations?

Comment: Yes, or in any language that allows for passing functions as parameters, continuation passing style is a style of programming in which you pass a continuation to each function, and the function calls the continuation when the function is finished.

Comment: I've just been reading p.3 of this https://www.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs152/2010sp/lectures/lec11.pdf   where the continuized version of λn,m.n+m is not given as your example λn,m,k.k(n+m), but as $CPS[[ e_1 + e_2 ]] k = CPS [[ e_1]] (λn. CPS [[e_2]] (λm.k (n + m)))\hspace{0.3cm}$   [where $n$ is not a free variable of $e$ and CPS[[ ·]] takes a lambda calculus expression, and translates the expression to a lambda
calculus expression in continuation-passing style]. Are these the same? If so, why is it written that way in the handout?

Comment: It looks to me like they have also used the method of "Currying" in that example, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying  So instead of calling $k(n+m)$ directly they call $(\lambda m.k(n+m))(m)$.  Any function of two or more variables can be transformed in this way into a sequence of function calls each of which just has one variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :) One more question: is there a rigorous definition of what a continuation is? Would you just define it inductively as a formula with at least one/an extra parameter?